# picking rows in pandas dataframe with top scores

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like :

```
Name Candidates Qualifier Score
AAA   AAA_1       Yes      0
AAA   AAA_2       Yes      10
AAA   AAA_3        No      20
BBB   BBB_1        No      1
BBB   BBB-2       Yes      10
BBB   BBB_3       Yes     50
```

I want to select the top two candidates in each "Name" having highest score. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort the df on 'Name' and 'Score' and then `groupby` on 'Name' and call `head(2)` to get the first 2 rows for each group:

```
In [228]:
df.sort(['Name','Score'], ascending=False).groupby('Name').head(2)

Out[228]:
  Name Candidates Qualifier  Score
5  BBB      BBB_3       Yes     50
4  BBB      BBB-2       Yes     10
2  AAA      AAA_3        No     20
1  AAA      AAA_2       Yes     10
```

Comment: The OP is after "the top two candidates in each Name".

Comment: The question asks the top two 'Candidates' for each name having the highest score, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: If you want to add in my sorting feel free and then I can take delete mine

Comment: @SirParselot I could do but the OP hasn't specified what the desired result should look like and sorting is trivial here

Comment: I just figured OP would want it like it's setup originally and yes it's trivial

Answer (score 0):

Well seeing as I ended up with the same method as EdChum's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33106757/5012922) here is my contribution which is a bit long for a comment. If you want to print the names and candidates in order you can use one more `sort` statement like so.

```
Sorted = df.sort(['Score'], ascending = False).groupby('Name').head(2)
print Sorted.sort(['Candidate'], ascending = True)

  Name   Cand  Score
1  AAA  AAA_2     10
2  AAA  AAA_3     20
4  BBB  BBB_2     10
5  BBB  BBB_3     50
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the "by name" part of the question.

Comment: @DSM Yes I realized that after posting. I am working on a proper answer at the moment